# DependencyService.Get<IMessage>() always returns null or says I don't have a default constructor defined depending on params

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have read everything I can find and tried all of them,but cannot get past this null reference exception. Here is my code that is failing

```
 try
        {
            Analytics.TrackEvent("In iCloud.aspx.cs, BackUpClicked Date = " + sDate.Date + " autoId = " + Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Properties["autoId"]));
            var count = await DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().BackupToiCloud(Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Properties["autoId"]), sDate.Date.ToString("MMddyyyy"));
            EntMessage = count.ToString() + " Records Backed Up";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            Analytics.TrackEvent("Exception in BackUpClicked Method" + ex.ToString());
        }
```

I have read that I need to implement Dependency service for both platforms I have in my solution so I have the following line below in my AppDelegete.cs for iOS and for Android, I have the same line in my MainActivity.cs

```
Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<MessageService>();
```

In my iOS project, I have the MessageService defined as follows,

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MileageManagerForms.iOS.MessageService))]
namespace MileageManagerForms.iOS
{
    public class MessageService : IMessage
```

and for the android project I have MessageService defined as follows,

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MileageManagerForms.Droid.MessageService))]
namespace MileageManagerForms.Droid
{
    public class MessageService : IMessage
```

I am not quite clear what else I need to do. One thing I found was promoting this syntax to register, but when I did that, it told me I was missing the default constructor from MessageService which is bogus.

```
 Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<IMessage, MessageService>();
```

In looking at examples of code, it appeared that the registration of the dependency service had to happen under this line of code in the appDelegate and MainActivity,

```
LoadApplication(new App());
```

is this correct? I know there are a thousand posts specifically on this subject, but it you can see something I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks so much.

Comment: does `MessageService` have a default constructor or not?  You didn't post any of the actual code for that class

Comment: Yes, MessageService does have a default constructor in Androis and iOS projects

Comment: you do not need to use both `Register` and the `Dependency` attribute - pick one or the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify these details (for Android):

1. `IMessage` is a public interface in your `shared project` MileageManagerForms:

```cs
namespace MileageManagerForms
{
    public interface IMessage
    {
    }
}
```

2. What is purpose of attribute `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MileageManagerForms.Droid.MessageService))]`?
   Try commenting that out.
3. Could there be definitions of `IMessage` or `MessageService` that you are getting from somewhere else? Maybe a library that you use?

Try the following sanity check:

In `OnCreate`, after Xamarin Forms Init, put these 3 lines:

```cs
IMessage ms = new MessageService();
Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<IMessage, MessageService>();
var messageService = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Resolve<IMessage>();
```

- If the first line complains, then you aren't doing what you think you are doing. Hover over `IMessage` and `MessageService`, to see what Namespace they are in.
- Currently, the second line is complaining for you. If the first line compiles and runs without complaint, I haven't found any way to have the second line give the error you got. (I can cause other errors, like a null exception, by doing it before XF is init'd).
- If the third line results in `messageService` having a `null` value (hover over it, or check in Locals), then there is some other problem, TBD.

Comment: Thank you so much. I removed the line, [assembly: Dependency(typeof(MileageManagerForms.Droid.MessageService))] from both my Android and IOS MessageSerevice classes and added the 3 lines above that you suggested, IMessage ms = new MessageService();
Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<IMessage, MessageService>();
var messageService = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Resolve<IMessage>(); and now it works. Again, thank you so very much!

Comment: Good! The first and third lines were just a test to help figure out what was wrong. You should be able to remove them now, keeping just the middle line.